# Slow observation buffer update warnings in move_base

Tags: navigation, move-base, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using a sick laser (lms-200) and a kinect camera as my sensors, mounted on a pioneer 3-at. I'm running ros diamondback on ubuntu 10.10, running gmapping with the nav stack.

I know from rostopic that the laser is publishing scans at around 10hz, however, I keep getting such warnings from move_base.

> [ WARN] [1317944137.717114373]: The
> /scan observation buffer has not been
> updated for 5.18 seconds, and it
> should be updated every 5.00 seconds.
>
> [ WARN] [1317944137.917127486]: The
> /scan observation buffer has not been
> updated for 5.38 seconds, and it
> should be updated every 5.00 seconds.
>
> [ WARN] [1317944138.117128035]: The
> /scan observation buffer has not been
> updated for 5.58 seconds, and it
> should be updated every 5.00 seconds.
>
> [ WARN] [1317944138.317100694]: The
> /scan observation buffer has not been
> updated for 5.78 seconds, and it
> should be updated every 5.00 seconds.
>
> [ WARN] [1317944138.581264407]: Map
> update loop missed its desired rate of
> 1.0000Hz... the loop actually took 4.9738 seconds

Why does it take so long for the scan msg to register with move_base? Is it related to the slow map update warning at the bottom? The result is that it takes minutes to plan any simple path. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11451/slow-observation-buffer-update-warnings-in-move_base/) by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on 2011-10-07**:
The system load's high when running gmapping and navigation, even when I turn down both the controller and map update frequencies to 1. When I run nav with a static map (eg. amcl), the system load drops significantly and nav functions fine. Any other ways of reducing load to run gmapping and nav?

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-10-07**:
What does the system load look like on the machine you're trying to use to run the navigation stack? If its high, you might consider turning down the controller and map update frequencies.

**Comment by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on 2011-10-07**:
It's sick lms-200.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-10-07**:
What model of Sick scanner are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the comments above from @eitan and @xylo.  The problem was that the computer was being overloaded by the navigation stack trying to run too fast.  The solution was to turn down the update rates for the controller and update frequency.  More details of parameters can be found on the [navagation tuning guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2